# Calling ant file through java code

Tags: java, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to call Ant or NSIS scripts from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440295/is-it-possible-to-call-ant-or-nsis-scripts-from-java-code)

I need to call an ant build in java code. I try to use Runtime class. I dont know how to give the ant build  to the following code. I tried to assign the entire ant script to a string, it wont work. Any suggestion

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question should help you:

[Is it possible to call Ant or NSIS scripts from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440295/is-it-possible-to-call-ant-or-nsis-script-via-java-code)

And this one has a good link in the accepted answer explaining running commands from java in general:
[Collect Linux command output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441304/collect-linux-command-output)

Answer (score 0):

Try "cmd /c ant build", that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use [Gant](http://gant.codehaus.org/) which is nothing else than using Groovy for scripting Ant scripts instead of using xml.
Groovy scripts compile to Java bytecode - pure Java.