# Get RSS memory usage of java process through API

Tags: java, memory

We have a java program that directly uses native memory through JNI. Therefore, we want to monitor RSS memory (not just JVM) of java program to ensure no memory leak. The results should be equivalent to value returns in `top` command. Does java expose certain API for this?

Comment: why not just run top?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441304/collect-linux-command-output